# Angular2: base component - panel with title and content

Tags: angular

I'd like to create component for representing base panel (with HTML template). Then I'd like to inherit this base class but specifying only title (as class attribute/function or `@Input`) and content (as `template` or `templateUrl` in `@Component` decorator).

```js
@Component({
    template: `
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="title">{{title}}</idv>
            <div class="content">???</div>
        </idv>
    `
})
export class BasePanel {
    @Input()
    protected title: string = '';
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-panel',
    template: `MyPanel template - lorem ipsum`
})
export class MyPanel extends BasePanel {
    title: string = 'MyPanel title';
}
```

then in other template:

```html
<my-panel></my-panel>
```

or

```html
<my-panel title="My better panel"></my-panel>
```

The very good solution would be to deliver content between HTML tags:

```html
<my-panel title="My panel with content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    <p>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</my-panel>
```

**Edit 1**

The solution from @rinukkusu with ng-content is working.

But I'd like to have a possibility to create `BasePanel` component which would decorate derived component template.

Comment: I don't know what "which would decorate derived component template." means. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer In a component I'd like to put HTML only for panel content (with variables etc) and this would be decorated by HTML declaring padding, margins, border etc - same decoration for all panels in application. Preferably this decorating would be done by `BasePanel` - but this kind of thinking comes from PHP.

Comment: Sounds like `<ng-content>` explained below is the right thing to use.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance won't work with this, but you can leverage the `ng-content` tag however, so that it displays the original HTML.

**The component:**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-panel',
    template: `
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="title">{{title}}</div>
            <div class="content"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class MyPanel {
    @Input()
    protected title: string = '';
}
```

**Usage:**

```html
<my-panel title="My panel with content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    <p>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</my-panel>
```

---

> Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ihEcHjwzP9Noohv3siV?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: This is good solution for delivering content between HTML tags: But I'd like to have a possibility to create `BasePanel` component which would decorate derived component template.

Comment: This won't work, like I said and like Günter said in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't support extending components. In Angular composition is preferred over inheritance. There are answers that suggest custom decorators to support that but that is not compatible with the upcoming offline template compiler.

Comment: Preferring composition over inheritance is overall trend as it is more elastic approach. But what is the best approach to apply visual decorators? How to organize code to create only content of panels (there are plenty in the project) and not the surrounding HTML tags keeping in mind upcoming offline template compiler and DRY ? I can create subcomponents for header with title and content decorator start and content decorator end and use those components in every panel. I was doing like this in PHP many years ago and later technology elvolced.